# Failure scenarios for reliable UDP?

Tags: networking, udp, reliability

What could be good list of failure scenaros for testing a reliable UDP layer? I have thought of the below cases:

- Drop Data packets
- Drop ACK, NAK Packets
- Send packets in out of sequence.
- Drop intial hand shaking packets
- Drop close / shutdown packets
- Duplicate packets

Please help in identifying other cases that reliable UDP needs to handle?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "reliable UDP layer": you can't change the UDP layer (unless you are involved in IETF and have strong influence over standards bodies) **but** you can implement a Client protocol that sits **on top** of UDP. The said Client protocol can support reliability features.

Answer (score 2):

The list you've given sounds pretty good.  Also think about:

- Very delayed packets (where most packets come through fine, but one or two are delayed by several minutes);
- Very delayed duplicates (where the original came through quickly, but the duplicate arrived after several minutes delay);
- Silent dropping of all packets above a certain size (both unidirectional and bidirectional cases);
- Highly variable delays;
- Sequence number wrapping tests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried intentionally corrupting packets in transit?

Also, have you considered a scenario where only one-way communication is possible? In this case, the sending host thinks that the send failed, but the receiving end successfully processes the message. For instance:

1. host **A** sends a message to host **B**
2. **B** successfully receives message and replies with ACK
3. ACK gets dropped in the network
4. **A** waits for timeout and re-sends message (repeats steps 1-3)
5. host **A** exceeds retry count and thinks the send failed, but host **B** has in fact processed the message

Answer (score 0):

I have thought UDP is a connectionless and unreliable protocol and that is does not require and specific transport handshake between hosts. And hence there is no such thing as a reliable UDP protocol.

Comment: Yes, UDP *is* an unreliable protocol, but you can make it "reliable" by implementing TCP-like acknowledgement on top of UDP -- just like TCP does on top of the unreliable IP layer.

"Reliable" doesn't mean "flawless"; it simply means you will be notified of failures.

Comment: Thanks intgr for the heads up...did not realize that can be done! Cheers! :)

Comment: .... but the actual "server layer" i.e. UDP is still connectionless and unreliable. If one implements a protocol ontop of UDP, then it is just that: ANOTHER protocol ontop of UDP.

Comment: There is an emerging "stackoverflow for networking" site it seems: http://www.packetdrop.net/

Comment: Cool! Thanks jldupont for the heads up on that - look forward to checking it out...! ;)